# Apache2 ZF2 Raspberry Pi, internal server error

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2, debian, raspberry-pi

I have installed LAMP on my Raspberry Pi and then I have uploaded a ZF2 projects into /srv/www/. Unfortunately I get an internal server error when I want to launch the web site from the browser.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, dan@danprotti.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
> Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at 192.168.2.102 Port 80

The website (which has to run in an Intranet/LAN) is raspberrypi.goldfinger.com and I have the following config file in /ect/apache2/sites-available -> raspberrypi.goldfinger.com =>

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
ServerName raspberrypi.goldfinger.com
ServerAlias www.raspberrypi.goldfinger.com
DocumentRoot /srv/www/raspberrypi.goldfinger.com/goldfinger/public/
<Directory "/srv/www/raspberrypi.goldfinger.com/goldfinger/public">
DirectoryIndex index.php
AllowOverride all
AllowOverride Options
Options None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog /srv/www/raspberrypi.goldfinger.com/goldfinger/public/log/error.log
CustomLog /srv/www/raspberrypi.goldfinger.com/goldfinger/public/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

the .htaccess file comes from ZF2 and is:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should see the problem in your Apache logs, in the path you've specified in `ErrorLog`.

Comment: Also, upload a simple `phpinfo()` file to check that Apache/PHP is working on this machine.

Comment: ErrorLog does not show any error! I will see with phpinfo()

Comment: I solved it: Options FollowSymLinks